# Meaning of a piece of code in execv() system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In the source code of execve() system call 
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/exec.c#l177

there is a piece of code as:

```
#ifdef SPLIT_RSS_COUNTING
  add_mm_counter(mm, MM_ANONPAGES, diff);
#else
  spin_lock(&mm->page_table_lock);
  add_mm_counter(mm, MM_ANONPAGES, diff);
  spin_unlock(&mm->page_table_lock);
#endif
```

could you please explain its meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SPLIT_RSS_COUNTING` define is defined when the user controlled config of `CONFIG_SPLIT_PTLOCK_CPUS` is greater than the physical number of CPUs as defined by the config `CONFIG_NR_CPUS`. Without delving too deep, this means that the user can control for which amount of CPU does the kernel needs to lock the accounting. This configuration appears to be unique for ARM and PARISC CPUs.

When `SPLIT_RSS_COUNTING` is defined, the `add_mm_counter` needs to be protected from concurrent access, and so it is protected using spinlocks using the `mm->page_table_lock` lock.

A spin lock is the most basic way of synchronizing multiple CPUs. When the spin lock is entered and the lock is already held by a different CPU, the current CPU will enter a loop, checking the value of the lock flag. When the flag value changes to non-locked, the current CPU will take the lock and return from the `spin_lock` function.